# Suppose that f: [1,2] -> [0,3] is continuous. Show that there is some t exists in [1,2] such that f(t) +3 = 3t

Tags: real-analysis

So what I did was:
f(t) +3 = 3t

f(t) = 3t - 3

f(t) = 3(t-1)

then substituting in 1 and 2 to get 0 and 3.

then by IVT there exists t in [1,2] such that f(t) - 3 = 3t that proves the [0,3].

Comment: f(t)+3=3t at exactly one point, not all, and that is what you need to prove.  You can't assume something is true before you prove it.  You answer makes no sense.

Comment: Certainly f (t) = 3t -3 isn't the *only* continuous function.  You can't set f (t) +3 = 3t.  For every single continuous function from  [1,2] to [0,3] except one that isn't true.

Answer (score 3):

$g(t)=f(t)+3-3t$.  We have $g(1)=f(1)\geq 0$, $g(2)=f(2)+3-6=g(2)-3\leq 0$, thus since $g$ is continuous, there exists $t$ such that $g(t)=0$.